# What is the feasibility to run linear model for large amount of data?

Tags: machine-learning, algorithms, computational-statistics, large-data, time-complexity

I am looking for empirical approximations and guidelines on how many operations are required to run a linear model on a given amount of data, or if it's even feasible. Let's assume we use QR decomposition to solve least squares and use Newton-Raphson (fishier scoring) to solve generalized linear models.

The kind of answer I have in mind might be something like: "For least squares, if $n$ is on the scale of millions, and $p$ is on the scale of hundreds, we would need $O(p^3)$ operations. On most desktops, it takes a surprisingly short time, usually less than 1 minute to solve."

Comment: This isn't answerable without specifying the speed of the computer (chip, cache, memory, etc), & even then would be off topic here.

Comment: @gung I was trying to ask in "big O" sense, in the scale of seconds, minutes, days, or even months

Comment: @gung is right--but you could fix this up by asking in terms of an abstract model of computing and measuring time as the number of operations needed.  That kind of information will be applicable to an enormous range of hardware and software platforms, whereas specific times will assume some particular platform (which in short order will become obsolete).

Comment: At present, this remains off topic in my estimation. The "we need less than 1 minute to solve" depends on *the speed of the computer (chip, cache, memory, etc)*. However, @whuber's version of the question would be on topic (ie, I would vote to reopen).

Comment: @gung Revised again. Btw i have a desktop i built 10 years ago and a new desktop with water cooling. When working on solving linear systems they do not differentiate a lot. At most 2 times faster. Which i think using the scale of minites or days still make sense.

Comment: Best case scenario is $O(np)$ stochastic gradient descent technique. As the others say, particular times are not useful as they are entirely platform dependent. (Also, I would hazard a guess that you may not be using multithreaded BLAS if you only get 2x speedup)

Comment: @conjectures Thanks for your comments. In most cases, I give a big data to R `glm` for logistic regression. Then no response in couple of hours. That is why I am asking this question to see what is feasible or even worth to try...

Comment: I think base R is not multithreaded (dunno about other flavours). Try using a package like Julia GLM or vowpal wabbit.

Comment: @conjectures but what is the scale of $n$ and $p$, if I want to get the results say in couple of hours?

Comment: Wikipedia helpfully tabulates all the arithmetic operations, in detail, at the end of the section on QR decomposition at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition#Using_Householder_reflections.  As a practical matter, whenever you confront a big calculation, it should be your standard practice to benchmark smaller calculations. That typically takes only minutes. In conjunction with knowledge of the *asymptotic* scaling of the algorithm (you don't need the details) you can then extrapolate to estimate the resources you will actually need. You'll never have to wait indefinitely again.